# Lag with LibreOffice Calc when scrolling quickly through rows/columns

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have moved to LibreOffice from Microsoft Office, basically because I refuse to pay the Price for Microsoft Office.

I like LibreOffice as it offers everything I need and does pretty much the same job as Microsoft Office.

I find though that it is no where near as fluent. I use Excel/Calc for keeping my website Stock up to date and upload it to my Site as a CSV.

I find when I am quickly trying to scan through the spreadsheet to find a particular product it has a massive lag and keeps freezing, where as in Excel I could scroll right through without any issues.

Is there something I should do in order to aid with the performance and combat  this issue? I have noticed other issues, which are similar, such as saving, if I save a large document, it seems to save ok the first time but then if I make another change and need to save, it can take several minutes for the save to complete as the program stops responding, and on occasions it can stop responding for so long that I need to restart it.

I am now using Linux Mint but it was the exact same in Windows. I have around 1500 cells each using a VLookup.

Has anyone had similar issues and know any ways in order to make the performance slightly smoother?

I submitted an answer below which seemed to work but only for one day. As soon as I turned my computer on the next day it was back to the same old lag... The settings are all the same as they where when I ammended them.

Is there anything else I can try? or any other Office suites that might work better?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  What version of LO?  How big is your spreadsheet, and how complex is it (tons of formulas or mostly just data, how much complex formatting)?  What file format are you saving it in (are you using files you originally created in Excel and are still .xls or .xlsx, or are the files .ods)?

Comment: @fixer1234 I am now using Linux Mint but it was the exact same in Windows. I have around 1500 each using a VLookup. I think I may have solved the problem by increasing the memory allocated to Libreoffice and the Memory per object. Is it recommendable to do that? or is there something else I should maybe look at?

Comment: I've never even looked at manually manipulating memory allocations.  I can imagine that LO and MS Office use different tricks to make their products responsive, and that particular kinds of spreadsheets will be faster on one than the other.  It isn't surprising that speed of rendering the page would be different.  File saving speed could be affected by the need to translate file formats if you aren't using .ods (the native format).  It would be helpful to update the question with the details in my first comment.  (cont'd)

Comment: If you've managed to solve the problem via memory allocations, please post an answer describing how to do it.  That could be very useful to other readers.

Comment: Bummer on your solution.  Please add detail on the file format for context on the saving issue.  Was this created in Excel and now you're using the file in LO?  How much formatting does the sheet have?

Comment: @fixer1234 The initial file was created on Excel but moved over to Libreoffice when Excel subscription ran out. I am using VLookUps approx 3 per row over 1500 rows. so there is a lot happening. but the sheet updates work quickly it is the scrolling that has the massive lag and freeze

Comment: This is a long shot, but worth a try.  If the file is still stored as a .xlsx, save it as .ods.  LO will work with .xlsx files, but it isn't its native format.  If the spreadsheet is too big to fit entirely in memory, it may be translating the file on the fly as it sees other portions.  Saving it in the native format will eliminate that possibility.

Comment: That is the initial fix I tried but made no difference, then moved on to the fix below which had an instant effect but the effect didnt last long. My final fix has been moving to WPS Office which has zero lag but doesnt offer as good support for CSV, so am trying to use both together

Comment: Pain-in-the-butt workaround, but look at all the money you're saving.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem through ammending the Memory Allocations.

To do this I Chose the `Tools tab` and selected `Options`

within Options in the side menu I selected `Memory`

Under `Graphics cache` there are a few different options. I chose the top two `Use for LibreOffice` and `Memory Per Object` and increased the Memory Allocation for both.

> Use for LibreOffice I changed to 128mb
>
> Memory Per Object I changed to 20mb

This seemed to work for me. For other people, the memory you change it to may be different for better effects. I am going to have a play around with it to see if I can fine tune it further.